# If $f(..., v_{i+1}, v_i,...) = −f(..., v_i, v_{i+1},...)$ prove that $f$ is alternating

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, differential-forms

Let f be a $k$-tensor on a vector space $V$. Prove that $f$ is alternating if and only if f changes
sign whenever two successive arguments are interchanged:
$f(..., v_{i+1}, v_i,...) = −f(..., v_i, v_{i+1},...)$

---

I have showed this $(\Rightarrow)$ direction.
But I don't see how someone can show the other.

Let $σ$ be a permutation and $f(..., v_{i+1}, v_i,...) = −f(..., v_i, v_{i+1},...)$

$σf=f(v_{σ(1)},...,v_{σ(n)})$, for some $i\in \{1,2,...n\}$ it must be $σ(i)=1$ so with a finite interchanged of  successive arguments I can bring $σ(i)=1$ to the $1st$ place meaning to transport $v_1$ to the $1st $ place, $v_2$ to the $2nd$ etc.
so with a finite  interchanged of  successive arguments I can have
$σf=(-1)^mf(v_1,...,v_n)$.

If the sum of those  interchanged of  successive arguments is an odd number ($m=$odd) it's obvious that
$σf=f(v_1,...,v_n)$ and if it's even  $σf=(-1)f(v_1,...,v_n)$.

In order to prove what I want, it's enough to show that  if $σ$ is even, it corresponds to an even sum  of interchanged successive arguments and if $σ$ is odd then it corresponds to an odd sum  of interchanged successive arguments (or the opposite, I think would be the same)

I observe that if $σ$ is even (or same if it's odd), then that doesn't mean that the composition of transportations is successive
$ \sigma=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5\\
3&4&5&2&1\end{pmatrix} 
  \text{for instance}
:σ = (2 3)(1 2)(2 4)(3 4)(1 5)$

Can someone give a hint, because I don't think I can prove this with my current knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a permutation is even, there are lots of different ways of writing it as the composition of an even number of interchanges, but no ways of writing it as the composition of an odd number of interchanges. (and the reverse for odd permutations)

You can verify this by looking at the determinant of the corresponding permutation matrix. Any interchange has determinant -1, so any even permutation has determinant 1 and any odd permutation has determinant -1.

Comment: But how that helps ? Those interchanges don't mean they are  successive (as the example), are you saying that every even permutation can be written an even number of successive interchanges, because I don't think this is true.

Comment: Are you convinced that every permutation can be written as a composition of some number of successive interchanges? You produced an argument of this in your original question.

Comment: Yes I am, I even provide how to do it. But the whole point is that even permutations can be written as **even** successive interchanges. That I don't prove in my argument.

Comment: But if I use your answer, it can't be odd, so it must be even, and I am done ?